# Vaadin+Spring (without SpringBoot) with JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

i'm trying to combine vaadin with spring (without spring-boot) and java-annotation based configuration for the spring part.

The autowiring seems to work on the vaadin-ui part but not in "custom-ui classes" (e.g. "public class LoginScreen extends CustomComponent"). I'm getting an NPE or a null-object on SysOut.

Further i noticed that "@ComponentScan(basePackages={"net.myapp"})" is not scanning for beans. The only way to declare beans is in the CustomConfiguration itself.

XML-Configuration is not something i prefer.

I'm following this Tutorial: [Link](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Spring)

CustomConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"net.myapp"})
@EnableVaadin
public class CustomConfiguration {

// this is working but i want to use componentscan!
@Bean
public String test() {
    return "test...";
}

@Bean
public TestBean testBean() {
    return new TestBean();
}

@Bean
public LoginScreen loginScreenBean() {
    return new LoginScreen();
}
```

}

SpringVaadinServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = Application.class)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SpringVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet implements SessionInitListener {

@Autowired
protected VaadinUIProvider applicationProvider;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory ctx = ((ApplicationContext) 
            getServletContext().getAttribute("applicationContext")).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    ctx.autowireBean(this);
}

@Override
protected void servletInitialized() {
    getService().addSessionInitListener(this);
}

@Override
public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {
    event.getSession().addUIProvider(applicationProvider);      
}
```

}

VaadinUIProvider.java

```
@SpringComponent
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class VaadinUIProvider extends UIProvider {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public Class<? extends UI> getUIClass(UIClassSelectionEvent event) {
        return Application.class;
    }

    @Override
    public UI createInstance(UICreateEvent event) {
        UI instance = new Application();
        System.out.println("applicationContext is null? " + applicationContext);
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(instance);
        return instance;
    }

}
```

SpringApplicationContextListener.java

```
@WebListener
public class SpringApplicationContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CustomConfiguration.class);
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("applicationContext", applicationContext);     
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }

}
```

Application.java

```
@Theme("mytheme1")
@SpringUI
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Application extends UI {

    @Autowired
    private TestBean testBean;

    @Autowired
    private String test;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        // working
        System.out.println("init testBean: " + testBean);
        System.out.println("init test: " + test);

        Window window = new Window();
        window.setContent(new LoginScreen());
        window.setClosable(false);
        window.setWidth("400px");
        window.setHeight("280px");
        window.setModal(true);
        window.setDraggable(false);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.center();
        addWindow(window);
        setSizeFull();
    }

}
```

And the following "custom-ui class"
LoginScreen.java

```
@UIScope
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginScreen extends CustomComponent {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "";

    final FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();

    TextField userName = new TextField();
    TextField passWord = new TextField();
    Button submit = new Button("Submit");

    @Autowired
    private TestBean testBean;

    @Autowired
    private String test;

    public LoginScreen() {
        userName.setCaption("Benutzername:");
        passWord.setCaption("Passwort:");

// not working (null)
        System.out.println("loginscreen test: " + testBean);
        System.out.println("loginscreen test: " + test);

        setSizeFull();
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate some help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> window.setContent(**new LoginScreen()**);

Spring should create `LoginScreen` if you want that `@Autowired` annotated fields become injected.

Just inject the `LoginScreen` instance in your `Application` class

Comment: with 
`@Autowired
    private LoginScreen loginScreenBean;`

and 

`window.setContent(loginScreenBean);`

the Beans in LoginScreen.java are still null

Comment: @hehe Not really, you are logging in the ctor, injection occurs after construction.