# Vaadin without Spring Boot Issue

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm currently doing a Vaadin Spring App that doesn't use Spring Boot. I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130870/vaadinspring-without-springboot-with-javaconfig) to load my Annotated Spring settings.The settings were loaded but then this exception pops up:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [poc.spring.vaadin.dashboard.config.SpringVaadinServlet] in context with path [/dashboard] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'poc.spring.vaadin.dashboard.DashboardUI': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider poc.spring.vaadin.dashboard.DashboardUI.viewProvider; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found no valid com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIID instance!] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found no valid com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIID instance!

This is my main UI Code:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 @Theme("dashboardTheme")
 @SpringUI()
 public class DashboardUI extends UI {

@Autowired
private SpringViewProvider springViewProvider;

@Autowired
private PostValuesService postValuesService;

SampleSideBar sampleSideBar = new SampleSideBar();
LoginComponent loginComponent = new LoginComponent();

private TransMonitoring getTransGrid() throws ParseException {

    Collection<PostValue> transList = postValuesService.getAllPostValues(null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            null, null, null, 100);
    System.out.println(transList.size());
    BeanItemContainer<PostValue> container = new BeanItemContainer<PostValue>(PostValue.class, transList);
    return new TransMonitoring(container);
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
    // root.setSizeFull();
    root.setMargin(true);
    root.setSpacing(true);

    root.addComponent(loginComponent);
    root.setComponentAlignment(loginComponent, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    setContent(root);

     Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, root);
     navigator.addProvider(springViewProvider);
}
```

And the view:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@UIScope
@SpringView(name = "")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements View {


public static final String VIEW_NAME = "";

@Autowired
private LoginService loginService;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    Button navBtn = new Button("Test");
    navBtn.addClickListener(e -> getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("dashboard"));

    setSizeFull();
    TextField textField = new TextField("UserName");
    PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField("Password");
    Button loginBtn = new Button("Login");
    Button cancelBtn = new Button("Cancel");
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    // layout.setSizeFull();
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(navBtn);
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(loginBtn);
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(cancelBtn);
    layout.addComponent(textField);
    layout.addComponent(passwordField);
    layout.addComponent(horizontalLayout);
    User user = loginService.getDetailsByUserName("h.sipalay");
    loginBtn.addClickListener(e -> new Notification(user.toString()).show(Page.getCurrent()));
    addComponent(layout);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // the view is constructed in the init() method()
}
```

Hope anyone can help me here

Thanks!

Comment: please don't add screenshots of your code.  Just put the code in the text (indent it by four chars) and SO will show it ok-ish.  The code then can be edited by others, used for the answer, and can be searched.

Comment: updated changed screenshots to code.